# c# excel range merge function is combining adjacent rows

Tags: c#, excel, merge, range

thanks for taking the time to try and help. I'm trying to merge two ranges independently, like so: (As in just merge the columns per row, not merge both rows together)

```
MyWorksheet.Range[MyWorksheet.Cells[2, 1], MyWorksheet.Cells[2, 15]].Merge();
MyWorksheet.Range[MyWorksheet.Cells[1, 1], MyWorksheet.Cells[1, 15]].Merge(true);
```

However, when I do so, it merges both ranges together for some reason.

But, when I use:

```
MyWorksheet.Range[MyWorksheet.Cells[3, 1], MyWorksheet.Cells[3, 15]].Merge();
MyWorksheet.Range[MyWorksheet.Cells[1, 1], MyWorksheet.Cells[1, 15]].Merge(true);
```

It doesn't merge the two ranges together. Why does excel merge the two ranges if they are adjacent, regardless of me explicitly setting the desired ranges? Is there a work around for this? I've tried it with and without the spillover argument in Merge() set to "true".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean merges adjacent rows? So In the resulting worksheet the `range[cell[1,1], cell[2, 15]]` is one cell? I tried your code and my rows didn't get merged.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I mean it's merging the two rows together like this: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhfcgr8iv546qp2/Merging_Adjacent_rows.png?dl=0)

It's interesting that it doesn't do that when you execute the code.

Comment: Another thing worth noting, is if I merge a range separately, it works correctly, so I know they aren't overlapping. Stranger still, if I do ranges:
MyWorksheet.Range[MyWorksheet.Cells[2, 1], MyWorksheet.Cells[2, 15]].Merge(true);
MyWorksheet.Range[MyWorksheet.Cells[3, 1], MyWorksheet.Cells[3, 15]].Merge();

It **doesn't** combine them. I checked the code, and there's nowhere else I'm modifying rows 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out the problem. I'm not exactly sure why, but this line of code was the culprit:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range OperatorInformation = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)MyWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "B2");
OperatorInformation.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
```

Somehow adding a horizonatl alignment to this range caused it to merge both rows. When I commented it out, everything works as intended. Interesting.